# XMLAGG equivalent in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

`select 
XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E, Customer_data, ',').EXTRACT ('//text()') ORDER BY                                                     Customer_data).GETCLOBVAL (), 
customer_id 
from customer_table`

This basically combines all the rows in the customer_table, which have the same customer_id. This works in Oracle and doesn't come with any restrictions for the row size it can process(greater than 4000).

I need a similar function in MS SQL Server which will do the same thing for me. I have tried using the 'STUFF' function, but it has a 4000 character limitation. 
Please help.

Comment: What is your MSSQL Server version?

Comment: I am on 2012 MSSQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STUFF doesn't have a 4000 character limitation.  EG

```
with q as
(
  select o.name
  from sys.objects o, sys.columns c
)
select 
datalength(
STUFF((Select ','+ q.Name
from q
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
)
q
```

outputs

```
q
--------------------
2624410

(1 row(s) affected)
```